# Restriction on a custom XSD sub-type

Tags: xsd, attributes

I have created an XSD subtype like this:

```
<xs:comlpexType  name=”sub_aspect”>
    <xs:comlpexContent>
       <xs:extension  base=”aspect”>
          <xs:attribute  name=”id”  type=”xs:boolean” />
       </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

This subtype adds the possibility for `<aspect>` to have the "id" attribute.

Now, I want to use it twice inside a tag, but it has to be once **true** and **once** false (the order is not important):

```
<parent>
  <aspect id=false>
   ...
   some content
   ...
  </aspect>

  <aspect id=true>
   ...
   some content
   ...
  </aspect>
</parent>
```

How would this be specified in XSD?

Comment: You must use `XSD-1.1`. [See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your requirements, your scenario can be achieved using XSD 1.0 through constraints.

- *maxOccurs* ensures the "twice" constraints
- *xsd:key* ensures "once true and once false"

Here is a mockup of the relevant parts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="parent">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="aspect" maxOccurs="2">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="PK">
            <xsd:selector xpath="aspect"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xsd:key>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

An unrelated piece of advice: try to avoid the use of Boolean values for *id* attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Why should I avoid using Boolean values for if attributes?

Comment: Just one other thing. I need it to be a subType because not always I need <aspect> to have the "id" attribute, so this whole question is only for the sub_aspect subtipe. 
Should I integrate the xsd:key structure from above into the subtype extension? How would this be done?

Comment: @user5040728 1) Many authors tend to give `id` the meaning of the [`xml:id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/). If you think of an `id` as a unique identifier, then a type with a domain of two possible values is rather unusual. 2) type/subtype doesn't matter: constraints work under elements only and so as long as you define them for the element containing your aspects, it should be fine.